# Puppet Apache vhost proxypassreverse configuration

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, puppet

I'm having trouble configuring an apache 2.4 vhost for kibana 4.1.1 in puppet 3 on ubuntu 14.04.

```
proxy_pass         => 'http://localhost:5601',
proxy_pass_reverse => 'http://localhost:5601',

Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter proxy_pass_reverse on Apache::Vhost
```

I can't find anything on the web even in the puppet apache module readme. Does anybody know how to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result needs to look something like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5601/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5601/
```

The corresponding configuration in your profile/role needs to look like this:

```
proxy_pass => {
  path => '/',
  url => 'http://127.0.0.1:5601/'
},
```

This is described in the [module documentation](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache).